# Push XML to another XML as child node using rails Nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

**Objective :**

Push xml to another xml using Nokogiri rails gem

Here is Xml :

**XML 1 :**

```
<Hotellist>
  <hotel>
   <Name>Taj</Name>
   <location>New york,US</Name>   
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
   <Name>Hotel Oasaka</Name>
   <location>California,US</Name>   
  </hotel>
</Hotellist>
```

**XML 2 :**

```
 <hotel>
   <Name>Hotel Sherin</Name>
   <location>London,Uk</Name>   
  </hotel>
```

I want to push the xml2 value to xml1 as another child using Nokogiri or any other smarter way , any help ?

Comment: Nokogiri is a `ruby` gem, it's not limited to rails developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml1 = Nokogiri::XML("<Hotellist><hotel><Name>Taj</Name><location>New york,US</Name></hotel><hotel><Name>Hotel Oasaka</Name><location>California,US</Name></hotel></Hotellist>")
xml2 = Nokogiri::XML("<hotel><Name>Hotel Sherin</Name><location>London,Uk</Name></hotel>")

xml1.children.first.add_child(xml2.children.first.clone)
```

Should get the work done.

Comment: Your answer is very much helpful , also i have another clarification , how to append xml2 has more than one hotel